# How to transform a day to a date after the input reference date?

Tags: python

In Python, for a given date and day of the week, how do I return the next date of the given day after the given reference date?

i.e. implement the following function:

```
  """
  Transform a day to the next date after the input reference date.

  :param day: Day in range 1-7, where Monday == 1.
  :param reference_date: Reference date.
  :return: Day transformed to date.
  """
def transform_day_to_date(reference_date: date, day: int) -> date:
    pass
```

Example call:

```
# Date for the Wednesday following 2125-05-08
my_date = transform_day_to_date(reference_date = date(2125,5,8), day=3)
```

Returns:

```
date(2125,5,9)
```

I have a [functional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685234/1859370) solution, but it is slow. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: When there is not `function that does what I want` you need to build it ! there can't be a built-in method for everybody's wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to :

- get the current weekday (`.weekday()` is `[0-6]` so `+1` needed)
- compute the number of day until the weekday you want, by a simple substraction

```
def transform_day_to_date(reference_date: date, day: int) -> date:
    if day not in range(1,8):
        raise ValueError("Parameter day: %s is not in range[1;7]")
    wkday = reference_date.weekday() + 1
    delta = (7 + day - wkday) % 7
    return reference_date + timedelta(days=delta)

# shorten
def transform_day_to_date(reference_date: date, day: int) -> date:
    if day not in range(1,8):
        raise ValueError("Parameter day: %s is not in range[1;7]")
    return reference_date + timedelta(days=((6 + day - reference_date.weekday()) % 7))
```

Test

```
my_date = transform_day_to_date(reference_date=date(2125, 5, 8), day=3) # 2125-05-09
my_date = transform_day_to_date(reference_date=date(2020, 5, 8), day=3) # 2020-05-13
```

Comment: Nice one. Like the modulus to give you the delta when the day number is less than the reference date day.

Comment: Ah, but I've now read the Help and it recommends not to be in a hurry :) I up-voted your answer in the meantime.

Comment: The alternative answer I have given is the one I have since used, but it is natural to be biased to ones own code :)

Comment: That is a good point, but personally I don't have to think so hard to understand it as with the timedelta calculation approach.

Comment: Your version is an OOM faster from quick test and I think your longer version is clear to read also. It doesn't quite satisfy everything though to my mind, in that it does not guard against invalid input. A result is returned for any invalid input day outside the valid range 1-7 (where as my answer raises KeyError). If you add a guard I will be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @Chris no because you didn't make any try by yourself , read the doc is not enough, you may try code to reach a solution first. In most cases when you show no code of try, your question is closed in a minute, you got lucky to get answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach I came up with:

```
def transform_day_to_date(reference_date: date, day: int) -> date:
  dates = [reference_date + timedelta(days=d) for d in range(0, 7)]
  days_with_date = {dt.weekday() + 1: dt for dt in dates}

  return days_with_date[day]
```